# What js file to add for grid functionality for the Kendo UI ASP.NET MVC SPA Template?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, kendo-ui, kendo-grid, kendo-asp.net-mvc

I just started working with the Kendo UI ASP.NET MVC SPA Template developed by Burke Holland. In an article Mr. Holland mentions that if we wanted to add a Kendo UI DropDownList to this application, we would add kendo.dropdownlist.min to kendo.js and then because of Kendo UI's integration with RequireJS, any other dependencies would be added automatically.

http://a.shinynew.me/post/78038782111/a-kendo-ui-asp-net-mvc-spa-template

I want to add the Kendo Grid, but I see that there is no "kendo.grid.js" file among the other Kendo scripts. So, does someone know what script(s) I need to add for grid functionality?

Thanks,

Arnold

Answer (score 0):

The grid is actually made up of a number of files.

> [Kendo Dependencies](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/getting-started/javascript-dependencies)

Also this link from Burke should help as well and is specifically targeted at the grid and how to leverage specific components

> [You Might Not Need A Grid](http://developer.telerik.com/featured/might-need-grid/)

Comment: Hi David. Yes, the Kendo Grid has 64 js dependencies, not all of which are included in the vanilla app. See: http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/getting-started/javascript-dependencies#grid. I suppose that I will have to download kendo.web.min.js or cherry pick the js files. I have read the article by Sebastian Witalec and Burke Holland. Unfortunately, I must replicate a demo that used the full functionality of the grid, so I have to deliver what the users expect.